# How can i add Autocomplete textbox changed event in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I add an MVC3 autocomplete textbox changed event?  Below is my code.

**My view code**

```
<div style="float: left">

States Filter :

</div>

<div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px">
   @Html.TextBox("Statestxt")
</div>

<div style="padding-left: 10px; float: left">
   <input type="image" value="submit" src="../../Images/FilterBrowse.gif" 
          alt="submit Button" />    
</div>
```

**My controller:**

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteAsync(string term)
{  
    var suggestions = from s in Adm.states
    select s.state_name;
    var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower()));

    return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]   
public ActionResult States(state stateModel, string _stateName, 
    FormCollection formvalues)
{  
   AdmDataContext Adm  = new AdmDataContext;

   if (Request.Form["Statestxt"] == null)
   {
      ViewBag.Error = "Enter State Name.";   
      ViewData["name"] = false;

      return View();
    }
    else
    {
        _stateName = Request.Form["Statestxt"].ToString();
        var record = (from state in Adm.states
                      where state.state_name == _stateName
                      select state).Count();

        if (record == 0)
        {
           ViewBag.Error = "Enter Valid State Name.";

           return View();

        }

        var _Stateid = from state in Adm.states
                       where state.state_name == _stateName
                       select state;

        int StateId = (int)_Stateid.First().state_id;
        var state1 = am.FindUpcomingStates2(StateId).ToList();

        if (state1 != null)
        {
            ViewData["name"] = true;
            return View("States", state1);
        }

     }
}
```

I want to change the data after entering Statestext.  Where can I write the code for the Textbox changed event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to call a Javascript function when the user changes the text.  There's an overload for the Html.TextBox helper that you can use for this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Statestxt", "", new { onkeyup = "fnAjaxAutocomplete(this)" })
```

Then your handler Javascript method would look like this:

```
function fnAjaxAutocomplete(element)
{
    var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("AutocompleteAsync")' + '?text=' + element.value;
    $.get(ajaxUrl(function(suggestionsJson) {
        // handle JSON result here
    });
}
```

Comment: @sampathkumar See above, I added what the Javascript method would look like.